# Phonegap facebook, html5 video, iAds issues

Tags: facebook, cordova, html5-video, iad

I'm trying to build android+iOS application via **phonegap build API**. I found that that this api has some *limitations*, but I want to make sure...

**1)** Implementation **Facebook features** to phonegap application is possible only by phonegap plugin, which is not able to add via build API.

**2) iAds** aren't also supported. I found some plugin which can handle this, but as in first point, it is not possible to add plugins via phonegap build API.

**3)** Playing video using **HTML5 video tag** doesn't work if operation system of device doesn't have installed needed codecs. And there is no other way how to be sure that some type of video will be playable on most androis/iOS devices.

...so when I want to build applications via phonegap API, I have to forget to use facebook, iAds and video(on all devices) ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question: in the case of facebook some facebook plugins exist, you may want to look here:

[http://www.mosacrea.com/how-to-post-to-the-facebook-wall-in-an-iphone-app-with-phonegap-facebook-connect-and-childbrother-plugin/ it uses the ChildBrowser plugin](http://eisabainyo.net/weblog/2011/06/25/how-to-post-on-facebook-wall-on-iphone-and-android-using-phonegap-plugins/)..

or here:

[http://eisabainyo.net/weblog/2011/06/25/how-to-post-on-facebook-wall-on-iphone-and-android-using-phonegap-plugins/ same thing but with a slightly different approach.](http://eisabainyo.net/weblog/2011/06/25/how-to-post-on-facebook-wall-on-iphone-and-android-using-phonegap-plugins/%20same%20thing%20but%20with%20a%20slightly%20different%20approach.)

hope it helps...